# How do I join two CSV files but only where 2nd file matches?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have 2 CSV files:

Objects File:

```
IP,MASK,DESCRIPTION
10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255,Rob
10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255,Mark
10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255,John
```

Services File:

```
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple
John,2.2.2.2,Green
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow
```

The objects file has 3000 lines in, the service file has around 500.

I want to create a new file that has the all lines from services with objects' fields added on where a match in the description is found. So the desired output would look like:

```
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service,IP,MASK
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple,10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255
John,2.2.2.2,Green,10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow,10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255
```

Comment: From your examples it doesn't look like that's the case, but just to confirm, the files *aren't* sorted on the field to join (`Rob`, `John`, `Mark`) right?

Comment: No there is no sorting in either file. So for each line the in service file the object file would need to be searched again to try and find a match if that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `join`:

```bsh
join --header -t, -11 -23 -a1 <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k1"; next} 1' services) <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k3"; next} 1' objects)
```

```bsh
join --header -t, -11 -23 -a1 <(
    awk '
        NR > 1 {
            print |
                "sort -t, -k1";
            next
        }
        1
    ' services
) <(
    awk '
        NR > 1 {
            print |
                "sort -t, -k3";
            next
        }
        1
    ' objects
)
```

- `--header`: treats the first line in each file as field headers, printing them without trying to pair them
- `-t,`: sets `,` as the input and output field separator
- `-11`: joins on field #1 of `services`
- `-23`: joins on field #3 of `objects`
- `-a1`: also prints unpairable lines from `services`
- `<(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k1"; next} 1' services)`: sorts `services` on column `1` excluding the header
- `<(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k3"; next} 1' objects)`: sorts `objects` on column `3` excluding the header

```
% cat objects 
IP,MASK,DESCRIPTION
10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255,Rob
10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255,Mark
10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255,John
% cat services 
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple
John,2.2.2.2,Green
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow
% join --header -t, -11 -23 -a1 <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k1"; next} 1' services) <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k3"; next} 1' objects)
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service,IP,MASK
John,2.2.2.2,Green,10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow,10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple,10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255
```

Comment: The output I get is:

DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service,IP,MASK

John,2.2.2.2,Green

Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow

Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple

Comment: @MattyM The command should do what you asked for (beside the output will be sorted on the joint field, which shouldn't be a problem for CSVs, especially since that's the key field), what is wrong with that exactly?

Comment: LOL, I can't put it in a grey box! or even put it on each new line, any way it appears the only lines that are joined are the header?

Comment: @MattyM Please run this command (it will post the output of the command in my answer to Ubuntu Pastebin) and post the link here so I can take a look at it: `join --header -t, -11 -23 -a1 <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k1"; next} 1' services) <(awk 'NR > 1 {print | "sort -t, -k3"; next} 1' objects) | pastebinit` (by the way you can enclose inline code in backticks (\`) to format it as such)

Comment: `DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service
,IP,MASK
John,2.2.2.2,Green

Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow

Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple`

Comment: Sorry I can't make it paste as I see it!

Comment: @MattyM You can't post code *blocks* in comments, please post the output on [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and paste the link to the output on Ubuntu Pastebin here

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15651348/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38017/discussion-on-answer-by-kos-join-two-csv-files-but-only-where-2nd-file-matches).

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have sqlite3 and python installed on your system, you could use this http://www.sqlet.com/.

The relevant sql command would be:

```
./sqlet.py -d',' -A file1.txt -B file2.txt 'select A3,B2,B3,A1,A2 from A LEFT JOIN B ON A3=B1;' | sqlite3
```

This requires that you remove the headers from the two files. The sqlet script must be extracted in the same folder where those two files are or modified accordingly.

I tried it on your example extract. It works:

```
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~/Downloads$ cat file1.txt
10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255,Rob
10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255,Mark
10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255,John
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~/Downloads$ cat file2.txt
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple
John,2.2.2.2,Green
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~/Downloads$ ./sqlet.py -d',' -A file1.txt -B file2.txt 'select A3,B2,B3,A1,A2 from A LEFT JOIN B ON A3=B1;' | sqlite3
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple,10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow,10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255
John,2.2.2.2,Green,10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255
```

Comment: +1 however I'm pretty sure there's a very similar (Python) script to do basically the same in the repositories (to use SQL to "query" files as tables). Can't recall the name though.

Comment: @kos thanks. Checked yours and  reciprocated as it does have the advantage of not requiring any additional installations. Its only that I am much more familiar with SQL syntax than awk. Icould not find anything similar in the repos (would be nicer though)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are not too huge, how about `awk`?

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4; next} $3 in a {OFS=","; print $3,a[$3],$2}' services objects
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service,IP,MASK
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple,10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow,10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255
John,2.2.2.2,Green,10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255
```

Comment: I just tried this but I get no output!?

Comment: @MattyM since you seem to be having trouble with other suggested methods as well, perhaps your CSV files have some undisclosed feature (such as Windows-style line endings)?

Comment: "all lines from services with the objects fields added on where a match in the description is found", so I *think* what they want to do is to print all lines from `services`, even those without a match in `objects`.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver you were correct windows files messing things up!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
join -t, -a2 -11 -23 <(head -1 f1.txt; tail -n +2 f1.txt | \
         sort -t, -k1,1) <(head -1 f2.txt; tail -n +2 f2.txt | sort -t, -k3,3)
```

- `<()` is process substitution syntax, `bash` will replace it with a file descriptor with the output of the command inside it as the content
- `head -1 f1.txt; tail -n +2 f2.txt | sort -t, -k1,1` will `sort` the first file on first field from second line to rest and the first line is added on top so that we can use it with `join`. Same goes for `f2.txt` with the field to `sort` according to is three.
- `join` will just join on first field of `f1.txt` and third of `f2.txt` as common fields.

**Example:**

```
$ cat f1.txt 
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple
John,2.2.2.2,Green
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow

$ cat f2.txt 
IP,MASK,DESCRIPTION
10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255,Rob
10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255,Mark
10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255,John

$ join -t, -11 -23 <(head -1 f1.txt; tail -n +2 f1.txt | sort -t, -k1,1) <(head -1 f2.txt; tail -n +2 f2.txt | sort -t, -k3,3)
DESCRIPTION,OrgIP,Service,IP,MASK
John,2.2.2.2,Green,10.10.3.96,255.255.255.255
Mark,3.3.3.3,Yellow,10.10.3.95,255.255.255.255
Rob,1.1.1.1,Purple,10.10.3.94,255.255.255.255
```